# Using $1 as a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, pattern-matching

I'm trying to parse a customisable block of text, which I load from a file.  Simplifying it a bit, let's say, I'm trying to convert every block of text which appears inside curly brackets into a thing you can click to be javascript-alerted with the aforementioned text.

Problem is, passing $1 into the alert.  $1 doesn't play like a variable.  anyway, it started OK:

```
var text='Information here: {Thanks for clicking the info link}';
text=text.replace(/{(.+)}/g,'[<span onclick=\"alert(\\'\$1\\')\">click me</span>]');
document.write(text);
```

So far, so good.  I click where it says "[click me]" and the message "Thanks for clicking the info link" comes up as a javascript alert.

But sometimes I want to put a message with a " or a ' into the curly brackets.

```
var text='Information here: {Thanks for clicking the "info" link}';
text=text.replace(/{(.+)}/g,'[<span onclick=\"alert(\\'\$1\\')\">click me</span>]');
document.write(text);
```

simply fails to alert.  If I 'view selection source', it gives:

```
Information here: [<span onclick="alert('Thanks for clicking the " info"="" link')"="">click me</span>]
```

I've tried every combination of escaping the " marks, but no joy.

I thought of replacing " with ", but $1 isn't a variable!

Any ideas?  And yes, I do want to do this!  :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Just create a function that alerts and call it. Don't muddle around trying to manipulate code using `replace`.

Comment: The replacing is kind-of what the whole project does.  The user creates a form-based document where the fiddly stuff is put in by replacing simpler code.  It enables me to do a lot of other stuff too boring to go into, but the summary is that I do want to replace stuff.  Also - the problem remains that, just as I can't use $1 as a variable, I can't pass it to a function - same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use single `\` for escaping `'` and although there is no need to escape `"` within single quoted string.

```js
var text='Information here: {Thanks for clicking the info link}';
text=text.replace(/{(.+)}/g,'[<span onclick="alert(\'$1\')">click me</span>]');
document.write(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether my idea holds any grounds at all here as the idea popped into my head - but what if you were to use (ignoring quotes, ironically) '"' rather than attempting to escape the quotes themselves?

Edit: I'm an idiot, use (without spaces) '& quot ;'

Comment: Ah - yes, it works, but when I edit (using an HTML form) the file which stores the & quot;, it gets translated to a quote!  Practical issue for me.